# Can we reopen this question on Experience Certificate in India?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question ([Is an Experience Certificate valid without bank statements showing salary credit?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/38825/3192)) was closed as "Unclear what you're asking". It has since been edited and the current version of the question is clear and on-topic. Please cast reopen votes if you agree.

The close votes were cast on the first version of the question. I am not certain why, but I suspect it was because of the English and use of several India-specific terms. Some terms, such as "agreement basic", were not even familiar to me, despite having worked in India.

The question did get edited a couple of times, which made things somewhat more clear, but it could not garner any reopen votes. My latest edit is pretty much the "cherry on top", and mainly improves the "flow" of the description.

---

In case you are wondering why I dug up a question over 2 years old, it is because I decided to go through my old answers in the long weekend, and came across this closed question.

Comment: As is, I gave it my vote to re-open.

Comment: It is 3 years old why do we want to reopen it?

Comment: Why not? We don't throw away old questions, so what's the problem with reopening?